# Does Pyrite react with HCl?

Tags: geochemistry

I was wondering if anyone has some experience regarding my question. The geochemical simulation of mixing a mole of pyrite with a kilogram of acidic solution (pH=1) shows that Pyrite almost remains intact (PHREEQC). Do lab observations confirm this?

Comment: I would expect it to react.

Comment: I would expect it to react, especially if there is oxygen (e.g. from the atmosphere) present, even in small amounts.  Not sure if PHREEQC assumes this.